# Working outside of application context; FlaskClient object has no attribute 'app_context'

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

We are getting `FlaskClient object has no attribute 'app_context'` with this test:

app.py:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

from blueprints import default, otherstuff
from global_vars import app, db


def generate_app():
    app.config.from_object('config.flask_config')
    db.init_app(app)


   # registering blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(default.default)
    app.before_request(oauth_package.authenticate_all_requests)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app = generate_app()
    flask_app.run(port=5002, debug=True)
```

testfile.py:

```
import unittest
import mock
from starter_file import generate_app
import flask
import blueprints


class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # creates a test client
        app = generate_app()
        app.testing = True
        self.app = app.test_client()
        # propagate the exceptions to the test client

    @mock.patch('blueprints.default.get_current_user_role')
    def test_qppage_without_coockie(self,  mocked_get_current_user_role):
        mocked_get_current_user_role.return_value = 'ap'
        with self.app.app_context():
            result = blueprints.default.home()
            print result
            # assert the status code of the response
            self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 302)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and `Runtime error: Working outside of application context` with this code:

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # creates a test client
        app = generate_app()
        app.testing = True
        self.app = app.test_client()
        # propagate the exceptions to the test client

    @mock.patch('blueprints.default.get_current_user_role')
    def test_qppage_without_coockie(self,  mocked_get_current_user_role):
        mocked_get_current_user_role.return_value = 'ap'
        result = blueprints.default.home()
        print result
        # assert the status code of the response
        self.assertEqual(result.status_code, 302)
```

Comment: Please include the `global_vars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in your TestBase class:

```
...

from flask import current_app

...

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.app = generate_app()


def setUp(self):
    """Set up application for testing."""
    with self.app.app_context():
        self.test_app = current_app.test_client()

# Here goes the rest of your code
```

Comment: We got the same error, `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`. Also `app.test_client()` is undefined, it should be `self.app.app_context()`

Comment: @codyc4321 I edited the asnwer. The `app` which undefined should be `current_app` imported from flask. See if it helps.

Comment: it seems we hadnt followed it right using current app, thanks

Comment: where does `generate_app` come from?

Comment: does not help to avoid Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.